# Is animation-fill-mode: forwards better than using from/to in keyframes?

Tags: css, css-animations

For this example, I'll use a simple box that, as an animation, pops into view using `opacity` and `transform: translate()`.

I can do this in two ways:

- Set the box's initial CSS to `opacity: 0` and `transform: translate(10px)`, then write a `keyframes` that just sets the `to` property. Then, persist the end state of the animation using `animation-fill-mode: forwards` (specified in the shorthand).

```css
.animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  animation: slide-in .5s ease-in-out forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation"></div>
```

- The second way to do this is to specify the initial state in the `keyframes` instead, and not on the element itself. I specify a `from` and a `to` state, and leave everything to the animation.

```css
.animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  animation: slide-in .5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation"></div>
```

Both ways seem to work well and so my question is:

**Is one of these options better than the other?**

I don't see any advantages/disadvantages that aren't based on opinion, so I'm looking for factual advantages (performance?, accessibility?)

Answer (score 1):

If a user has disabled transitions and/or animations, using the first approach the element would be not visible at all because you defined `opacity: 0` as a property of the element and not inside the `keyframes`.

So, the second approach at least ensures that the element is always visible, even when the animation can't run because of user's settings.

Note that this is not strictly related to the `animation-fill-mode` property, since you could still use it by slightly changing the CSS of the first snippet:

```css
.animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  animation: slide-in .5s ease-in-out forwards;
  
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation"></div>
```

Comment: That thought has occurred to me as well, is animation disabling something that can occur often? And yes it's not strictly related, but the `forwards` property can be left out of your code sample and it will work the same, where it _is_ needed in the other option.